# Call same event-handler for multiple events

Tags: jquery, event-handling, modal-dialog

While opening a jquery modal I would like to call an event-handler which counts the number of lines in a textarea field, like:

```
$(".modal").on("focus", function() {
    var textarea = $(this)[0],
        lines = t.value.split("\n").lenth;
});
```

This works, but I would also like to count the number of lines real-time while editting the textarea.

```
$(".textarea").on("onkeydown onkeyup", function() {
    var textarea = $(this)[0],
        lines = t.value.split("\n").lenth;
});
```

I would have to type the same lines twice or even more. Is there any shortcut?

Comment: so is `.modal` and `.textarea` the same element then ?

Comment: No, the textarea is inside the modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Rory I managed to find the solution

```
function get_code_lines(element) {
    var content = $(element).find("textarea.codeview").val(),
        lines = content.split("\n").length,
        html = '';
    for(i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        html += '<div><span>' + (i+1) + '.</span></div>';
    }
    $(element).find("div.line-nums").html(html);
    $(element).find("textarea.codeview").height((18*lines));
}    

$(".modal").on("focus", function() {
    get_code_lines($(this));
});

$(".codeview").on("keydown keyup", function() {
    var parent = $(this).closest(".modal");
    get_code_lines(parent);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the logic into a function which you can then attach to as many event handlers as you need. Try this:

```
function getLines() {
    var textarea = $(this)[0],
    lines = t.value.split("\n").length; //Note: fixed typo
}

$(".modal").on("focus", getLines);
$(".textarea").on("onkeydown onkeyup", getLines);
```

This assumes that `.modal` and `.textarea` are the same element, so that `this` within the function always refers to the same element.

If they do not refer to the same element, you can use `$.proxy()` to change the scope of the function:

```
$(".modal").on("focus", function() {
    $.proxy(getLines, $(this).find('.textarea'))();
});
$(".textarea").on("onkeydown onkeyup", getLines);
```

Comment: Close, except I have 2 modals om the same page and both have a textarea. Using this function will return the number of lines of the first textarea